# Parse tokens in {curly braces}

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to parse out the strings enclosed in `{}` from the following paragraph using T-SQL and then display them.

> Here is a test sentence with a {Term1}. Sometime, a {Term2} could be a word or phrase like {Phrase Term3}. {Term2} is repeated. Some Terms could be a plural form of a another Term like {Term2}s. Here is a real {Simple} Term.

Desired results:

```
Term1
Term2
Phrase Term3
Term2
Term2
Simple
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this in T-SQL? Seems like a better for C# or anything else, really.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a multi-statement table-valued function, but I really think this type of parsing is much better left to more powerful languages. This will handle tokens `{up to 255 characters}` and input strings up to about 8,000 characters depending on version of SQL Server. If you need more, replace `sys.all_columns` with [your own numbers table](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1). Note that I did not go to any effort to protect from invalid token sequences...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ParseTokens
(
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @token1 NVARCHAR(255),
    @token2 NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS @t TABLE([Index] INT IDENTITY(1,1), Item NVARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @t(Item) 
    SELECT SUBSTRING(x, 1, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@token2, x)-1,-1),255)) 
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT Number, x = SUBSTRING(@string, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@token1, @string + @token1, Number) - Number)
      FROM
      (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
          FROM sys.all_columns
      ) AS n(Number) WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@string))
        AND SUBSTRING(@token1 + @string, Number, LEN(@token1)) = @token1
    ) AS y
    ORDER BY Number OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

    DELETE @t WHERE [Index] = 1;

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

Sample usage - on a stand-alone string:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @x = N'foo{bar} and think {splunge}';

SELECT Item FROM dbo.ParseTokens(@x, '{', '}') ORDER BY [Index];
```

Results:

```
Item
-------
bar
splunge
```

Sample usage - against a table:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), n NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT @x SELECT N'Here is a test sentence with a {Term1}. Sometime, a {Term2}
  could be a word or phrase like {Phrase Term3}. {Term2} is repeated. Some Terms
  could be a plural form of a another Term like {Term2}s. Here is a real
  {Simple} Term.';

INSERT @x SELECT N'Hello {foo} there {bar} ...';

SELECT t.ID, p.Item
 FROM @x AS t
 CROSS APPLY dbo.ParseTokens(t.n, '{', '}') AS p;
```

Results:

```
ID     Item
----   ------------
1      Term1
1      Term2
1      Phrase Term3
1      Term2
1      Term2
1      Simple
2      foo
2      bar
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your string to XML by replacing all `{` with a start element and all `}` with a closing element and then query the XML for the tokens.

```
declare @S nvarchar(max)
set @S = N'Here is a test sentence with a {Term1}. Sometime, a {Term2} could be a word or phrase like {Phrase Term3}. {Term2} is repeated. Some Terms could be a plural form of a another Term like {Term2}s. Here is a real {Simple} Term.'

select T.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Token
from (select cast(replace(replace(@S, N'{', N'<token>'), N'}', N'</token>') as xml)) as S(X)
  cross apply S.X.nodes('token') as T(N)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22606)

Comment: Oh, you and your fancy XML! (+1)